# Thus vs. Hence in motivation for action taken

Tags: adverbs

Which of the below is correct?

1. Many people had just eaten. However, I was hungry. Hence I went for dinner.
2. Many people had just eaten. However, I was hungry. Thus I went for dinner.

Additionally, would "so I went for dinner" be better than both?

Comment: https://painintheenglish.com/case/4452/

Comment: Yes, 'so' would definitely be the best choice for describing an everyday situation. 1. and 2. sound as though going for dinner is the explanation of a complicated problem.

Comment: @KateBunting So if we are talking about academic english, 1 or 2 would be better?

Comment: @ArchieAzares those uses are obsolete. I'm not convinced by what it wrote at all.

Comment: The meanings in Archie's link are not obsolete. "Thus" means "in this way". "Hence" originally meant "from here" and now means something like "following on from this train of reasoning".  So, yes, you would use them in an academic context.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks for the corrections. If "thus" means "in this way", 2 makes no sense, is it correct? One might say "... However, I was hungry and went my way home, thus I could have dinner"

Comment: @Zuoanqh You are right, 2. doesn't really make sense. Your new example is OK, though a bit formal.